# there has a error for route protection in react js using provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
authContext.tsx

import { createContext, useState, ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

type AuthContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  setIsAuthenticated: (value: boolean) => void;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  setIsAuthenticated: () => {},
});

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');

    
    if(user)
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  
  }, []); 

  const authContextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }),
    [isAuthenticated] // add a dependency array with the isAuthenticated state
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

index.tsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MainLayout } from '../containers/layout';
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from '../containers/views/home/home';
import Login from '../containers/views/login/login';
import ForgotPassword from '../containers/views/forgotpassword/forgotpassword';
import SetNewPaasword from '../containers/views/setnewpassword/setnewpassword';
import CheckMail from '../containers/views/checkmail/checkmail';
import { AuthLayout } from '../containers/layout';
import UserList from '../containers/views/user/userList';
import CustomerList from '../containers/views/customer/customerlist';
import MasterView from '../containers/views/master/MasterView';
import { LayoutProvider } from '../context/layoutcontext';
import LoanList from '../containers/views/loan/LoanList';
import OfferCustomerList from '../containers/views/offers/offerCustomerList';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/authcontext';

const Index = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
  return (
    <LayoutProvider>
      <Routes>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
            <Route path='/app' element={<MainLayout />}>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='admin' element={<MasterView />} />
              <Route path='user' element={<UserList />} />
              <Route path='customer' element={<CustomerList />} />
              <Route path='transaction' element={<LoanList />} />
              <Route path='offers' element={<OfferCustomerList />} />
            </Route>
           
        ) : (
          
              <React.Fragment>
                <Navigate to='/app' replace />
              </React.Fragment>
          
            // <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        )}
        <Route path='/auth' element={<AuthLayout />} />
        <Route path='/forgotpassword' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route path='/checkmail' element={<CheckMail />} />
        <Route path='/setnewpassword' element={<SetNewPaasword />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/app' replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </LayoutProvider>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

i am wrapped Router with Auth provider but the error is " Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render." how to resolve this error